# Shorthand for `any` on a TS interface

Tags: typescript, tsc

I accidentally got this and it seems to work:

```
export interface ITestBlockOpts {
  desc: string,
  title: string,
  opts: Object,
  suman: ISuman,
  gracefulExit,
  handleBeforesAndAfters, 
  notifyParent
}
```

for the lines:

```
 gracefulExit,
  handleBeforesAndAfters, 
  notifyParent
```

is that syntax short for

```
  gracefulExit: any
  handleBeforesAndAfters: any
  notifyParent: any
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. the TypeScript compiler has an option to assume untyped variables should be typed as `any`. This is [the `noImplicitAny` option](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/options/noImplicitAny.html) which is `false` by default.

It exists primarily to allow for easier conversion from JavaScript (of which TypeScript is a strict superset-of, i.e. all valid JavaAscript is valid TypeScript when `noImplicitAny == false`).

If you're using TypeScript in a greenfield or all-TypeScript project then you should work with `noImplicitAny == true` to ensure that you always use typed variables and fields.

Note that in TypeScript, if an interface member has an `any` type (whether implicit or not) it is not the same thing as an optional (`undefined`) member.

...so these interfaces *are* equivalent:

```
interface Foo {
    a: any           // explicit `any` type
}
interface Bar {
    a                // implicit 'any' type
}
```

...but these interfaces are not equivalent:

```
interface Foo {
    a: any
}
interface Baz {
    a?: any          // explicit `any` type, but `a` can also be `undefined`
}
interface Qux {
    a?               // implicit `any`, but `a` can also be `undefined`
}
```